# Como alterar a url da propriedade "background"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho essa função que altera o src de uma img:

```
window.document.images['img'].src = n_src;

<img src="" name="img"/>
```

Mas queria alterar o background url do style:

```
<div name="img" style="background: url()"></div>
```

Qual a melhor forma para fazer essa função?

Answer (score 5):

Para mudar o background podes usar assim no JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("[name='img']").style.backgroundImage = 'url(...)';
```

O melhor seria fazer isso no CSS, mas em resposta à tua pergunta deves usar então:

> **elemento**.style.backgroundImage = ...

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/5m47veLa/show/

Comment: Só fiquei com uma duvida o link da minha imagem vinha de outra função que era o n_src; como posso fazer essa alteração?

Comment: @Josimara nesse caso podes fazer `elemento.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + n_src + ')';`

Comment: Tentei desse modo antes não tive resultado

Comment: document.querySelector("[name='img']").elemento.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+n_src+')';

Comment: @Josimara o que está dentro de `n_src `? o que dá `alert(n_src);`?

Comment: @Josimara retira `elemento` desse código que colocaste em cima... deve ser somente `document.querySelector("[name='img']").style.backgroundImage = 'url('+n_src+')'; `

Comment: no n_src  esta o link de uma imagem

Comment: Não estou tendo resultado ainda, mas no seu exemplo no jsfiddle funcionou.

Comment: Se eu coloco o link da imagem direto ali dentro esta indo mas se eu coloco o +n_src+ já não pega.

Comment: @Josimara onde estás a defenir essa variável? Podes colocar mais código para eu tentar descobrir onde estás a a fazel mal?

Comment: @josimara, você tentou retirar o atributo style do HTML como eu recomendei?
Caso tenha tirado, copie e cole exatamente como você criou sua variável na pergunta, por favor...

Answer (score 5):

Modifique nesse caso utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

```js
var n_src = 'http://arcticmonkeysbr.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/maxresdefault1.jpg';


document.querySelector("[name='img']").addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + n_src + ')';
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div name="img"></div>
```

OBS.: retire o atributo style do HTML, você pode estar tendo dificuldade devido a sobrescrita do valor.

Se ainda não estiver conseguindo, no console do navegador digite console.log(n_src) e comente exatamente qual foi o valor retornado.